# A simple question about homogeneous manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $K$ a compact subgroup of $G$. Then since $K$ acts freely and properly on $G$ by translation, we can form the homogeneous manifold $K\backslash G$.

**Question**: is the map $K\times (K\backslash G)\rightarrow G$ defined by $(k,[g])\mapsto kg$ a diffeomorphism?

Actually I can't see why this isn't true, but I find it hard to believe because it would imply that any Lie group $G$ is always a principal $K$-bundle over $G/K$.

Edit: I meant free principal $K$-bundle.

Comment: If $K$ acts freely and properly on $G$, shouldn't the manifold you form be $G/K$?

Comment: Well $K$ can either multiply from the left or from the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map you write out is not well defined (since you choose a representative of a coset and the map is not independent of this choice). What happens is that $G$ is a principal $K$-bundle over $K\backslash G$, so locally isomorphic to a product, but not globally. The latter statement basically means that locally you can choose representatives of cosets smoothly.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas Cap, indeed it’s not well-defined! What’s an easy example where there is no smooth section of the principal bundle $G\rightarrow G/K$?

Comment: Just take $SO(3)\to SO(3)/SO(2)\cong S^2$ (given by the action of $SO(3)$ on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$). The resulting principal bundle is the oriented orthonormal frame bundle of $S^2$. If this were trivial, then also the associated bundle $TS^2$ would be trivial which contradicts the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: As a follow-up question: would you still have a measure-theoretic relation $L^2(G)\cong L^2(K)\otimes L^2(K\backslash G)$, even though there is no diffeomorphism $G\cong K\times K\backslash G$?

Comment: Since these are all separable Hilbert spaces, there should be no problem on the level of spaces. I am not sure what happens if you view them as representations of $K$ (I would rather guess that they are non-isomorphic, but I am nor sure).